# How to prevent invalid clicks from proxies

Tags: ppc

What would be the best and cost effective solution to prevent invalid clicks from PPC.

Answer (score 1):

Most, but not all, proxies set the X-Forwarded-For header in the http requests.  You can read about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For   One solution would be to use this header when it is available.